# c# streamwriter add line on file creation

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I am successfully writing data to csv files (yay!) in a Console App. Streamwriter is excellent for me up to now.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, true))
{
    writer.WriteLine(strToSave);
}
```

This codes appends to an existing file or, if it doesn't exist, creates a new file first then writes.

What I want it to do is, if the file doesn't exist, create the file, write a header line for the csv columns, then write the data as normal. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you're sure no other process will be messing with the file at the same time, you could just use `if (File.Exists(file))...` to take a different path.

Comment: You can use the FileInfo classes exists method before opening the stream to check if it exists

Comment: If you haven't tried anything, what you can do is; check if file exists. If not, run your header writing code, and then business-as-usual.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could first check weather the file exists using `File.Exists()` method. If the file already exists, you don't need to write the header, and if the exists value is `false`, write header (supposing that the header of the `.csv` is in the variable `header`) and then write the text you want.

```
        bool exists = File.Exists(file);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file, true))
        {
            if(!exists)
                writer.WriteLine(header);
            writer.WriteLine(strToSave);
        }
```

Comment: Very neat solution indeed!

Comment: Thanks, its the simplest one I could write from the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length property of a stream

```
using(var stream = new FileStream("file.name", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    if (stream.Length == 0)
    {
        // Write header here
    }
}
```